# Achar registro com expressão regular no mssql

Tags: sql-server, regex

Eu tenho uma coluna que armazena dados no seguinte padrão `#campo#=valor;#campo#=valor` (e assim por diante)

ex: `'#aaaa#=1111;#bbbbb#=2222;#cccc#=33333'`

Porém, adicionaram `;` dentro do valor e eu queria localiza-los, preciso achar os registros que possuem `;` e logo após qualquer coisa que não seja o #

ex de registro a ser encontrado: `'#aaaa#=1111;#bbbbb#=2222;#cccc#=33;333'`

A base de dados é MSSQL.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o seguinte regex: `;[^#]` e o regex você pode utilizar baseado nessa query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207975/9101590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No SQL Server não existe implementação nativa de *regular expression*. O que mais se aproxima é a definição de padrão (*pattern*), utilizado em [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179859(v=sql.120).aspx) e na função [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188395(v=sql.120).aspx).

A forma de armazenar atributos e valores parece ser uma implementação da modelagem de dados [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#EAV_versus_row_modeling).

Como exemplo, considera-se que o nome da tabela é EAV e que o nome da coluna é AtribValor. Eis duas formas de se obter as linhas que possuem `;` intruso.

```
-- código #1
SELECT AtribValor
  from EAV
  where AtribValor like '%;[^#]%';
```

e

```
-- código #2
SELECT AtribValor
  from EAV
  where patindex('%;[^#]%', AtribValor) > 0;
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a seguinte regex para isso :

```
#([^#]*)#=([^#]*)(?:;|$)
```

#### Explicação

- `#([^#]*)#=` - Vai capturar o "atributo".
- `([^#]*)` - Pega o valor
- `(?:;|$)` - Grupo de não captura que diz que o valor vai terminar com `;` ou `"final de string"`

Veja em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/2IIsF1/1)

#### Adendo

Caso queira pegar todas as sequencias possíveis de um vez :

```
(#([^#]*)#=([^#]*)(?:;|$))+
```

#### No SQL-Server

Nunca usei Sql Server, então não sei disser com exatidão como aplicas, mas aqui tem dois links que creio poção ajudar.

[How to use a REGEX in an SQL SELECT query](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/sql-server/how-to-use-a-regex-in-an-sql-select-query/)
[SQL Server Regex](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL)